# Windows Form Compiles to Different Size than desinger

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This may be fairly obvious as I cant find it on Google but I have a windows form of a given height and width in the VS Designer and it looks perfect.

The object inspector and the ViewDesigner.VB all match up.

But when it gets compiled the window is noticeably bigger and brings with it a whole heap of wasted space around the edges. This is more than just ClientSize etc. This is a good inch or two.

Any idea whats causing it? It's not a resolution issue as this happens on the same machine.

Comment: can you post some screen shots.?

Comment: Ah, did you use the zoom function of Visual Studio? This fooled me the first time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference this was nothing I was doing, it was coded into the larger application to retain window states.

So it simply re-sized to either what it was or what it thought it should be.

Thanks for the help and suggestions either way.